# Excel compile error: Can't assign to read-only property

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting an error in Excel regarding assignment to a read-only property with the following code:

```
1    Sub GetSheets()
2    Path = "C:WHERE MY DOCUMENTS ARE KEPT"
3    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.CSV")
4      Do While Filename <> ""
5      Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
6         For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
7         Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
8      Next Sheet
9         Workbooks(Filename).Close
10         Filename = Dir()
11      Loop
12    End Sub
```

Comment: on which line does error occur please?

Comment: There is no compile error in the above code. Do you have any other code in your VBA Project? I guess the error is somewhere else :)

Comment: I am putting the code in "This workbook" to compile the data. The answer below confuses me. (and forgive me I'm new) but Currently the path is the location to where all the .csv files are located. The only error code that I see is telling me what was stated above.

Comment: The error does appear to be within the path.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you have the posted code in the `ThisWorkbook` module ?

`ThisWorkbook` represents the workbook itself, which has a built-in (read-only) `Path` property.

Rename `Path` to (e.g.) `myPath` and you should be OK.

```
Sub GetSheets()
    'best to use a Constant here...
    Const THE_PATH As String = "C:\WHERE\MY DOCUMENTS\ARE KEPT\"

    Dim Filename as String, wb As Workbook, Sheet As Worksheet

    Filename = Dir(THE_PATH  & "*.CSV")
    Do While Filename <> ""
         Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=THE_PATH & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)
         For Each Sheet In wb.Sheets
             Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
         Next Sheet
         wb.Close
         Filename = Dir()
      Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: wow, very good.  I can confirm if pasted into ThisWorkbook it does indeed give Compile error. Excellent.

Comment: I appreciate the help.

Comment: I am putting it in "thisworkbook" If I rename the path on line 2 to Path = my path i receive a similar/same error. My goal with this is to take the 500 files and merge them into one. This is what my thought was to use the "thisworkbook" if there is a better way to do this I am all ears. Thanks again

Comment: Sub GetSheets()
    Path = "C:\Users\chall\Desktop\Visual Basic"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.CSV")
      Do While Filename <> ""
      Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
         For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
         Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
      Next Sheet
         Workbooks(Filename).Close
         Filename = Dir()
      Loop
    End Sub

Comment: If I put Path = (e.g) "c:\users\chall\desktop\visual basic" That line turns red. My apologize for blowing  up your response.

Comment: You cannot use a variable named "Path" in that code module. Change the name of the variable to "myPath"